# Why did my Canon EOS 450D fail to save the entire photo?

Tags: raw, troubleshooting, canon-450d, data-corruption

After not being used for three months I got this (bottom right corner cropped from processed raw image by Canon's DFP):

[image]

(original RAW is available for download here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9271284/IMG_9766.CR2)

This was first photo taken that day, all photos taken after were saved ok. Is this a failing SD Card or first sign that my EOS is going bye bye?

Comment: Always format a card on the camera, no on the computer.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers doesn't matter where you format the card as long as you get the 'file system' correct

Comment: @Michael: I'd be shocked if that would cause this kind of problem.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Camera formats the card to FAT32 so your comment kinda makes no sense ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the raw file, the JPG preview looks fine, but there is about 1/6th of the RAW image that is blanked out.

It could have been a glitch in the camera, an error on the card, or an error in the transfer to your computer.

If you still have the image on the card, I'd try to transfer again.

Then reformat the card and see if it happens again.

If it does, try other cards, as Rowland suggested.

If other cards have the same issue, then suspect the camera.  Until then I'd think a faulty card or transfer is more likely.

Comment: Subsequent transfers from card yielded same results. I'll format the card to see if it will happen again.

Answer (score 0):

It's always worth trying to rule out a faulty camera first, by checking with other memory cards -- if the behaviour is consistent across cards, then it may be a fault with your camera, and you should contact your local friendly service centre